# PHP Wordpress Plugin Variable Not Echoing out Inline Style

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, plugins, shortcode

I am developing a Wordpress Plugin and It has a shortcode that I am using to print out content to a page/post.

In my plugin file I have initiated all menu pages and settings, I have 2 settings in the plugin admin page and one of them is Brand Color so users can change the branding color of the form the shortcode is spitting out.

The data is saved in the wp-options table in wordpress and all working ok, the problem is when i try to echo out the variable content nothing is happening?

What I have done:

I first added a Global array variable at the top of my Plugin php file:

```
    $options = array();

    options_init(){

        if(current_user_can('manage_options')):

           global  $options;

            if(isset($_POST['form_submitted'])){

              $hidden = esc_html($_POST['form_submitted']);

                if($hidden == 'Y'){

                    $Brand = $_POST['brand_color'];
                    $options['brand_color'] = $Brand;

                    update_option('general_info', $options);
                }   

            }
                $options = get_option('general_info');

         endif
     }
```

So now I have stored the data I then retreive the data and store it in my options variable. In another function I create the shortcode function and content to show on the screen, when the shortcode is used.

I first call my global variable then the output for the shortcode content.

```
add_shortcode('my-form', 'budget_form');
function budget_form() {
global  $options;   
  ?>
<div class="monkey-budget-planner-wrapper">
        <div class="monkey-header-wrapper" style="background:<?php echo $options['brand_color'] ?>">
       </div>
</div>

    <?php
}
```

Th problem is that the style is not being output, there is no errors and in the inspector i see the output is blank. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do a var_dump($options['brand_color']) I think its not what you expect

Comment: Yes Var Dump Shows NULL

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using a global and not just get_option('general_info'); at the top?

Comment: no not at all I was trying to be future proof just incase. If i just used get_option('general_info'); how would i access the brand_color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? You can combine some of your conditions also.

```
  options_init(){

        if(current_user_can('manage_options') && isset($_POST['form_submitted'])):

              $hidden = esc_html($_POST['form_submitted']);

                if( $hidden == 'Y'){

                    $brand = $_POST['brand_color'];

                    update_option('brand_color', $brand);
                }   


         endif
     }
```

Than you can use

```
    add_shortcode('my-form', 'budget_form');

        function budget_form() { 

          $color = get_option('brand_color'); ?>

          <div class="monkey-budget-planner-wrapper">
                 <div class="monkey-header-wrapper" style="background:<?php echo $color ?>"></div>
          </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

if you need more than one option set, than just create more with `update_option(),` if you are going to set page specific values, I would suggest `update_post_meta` and `get_post_meta()`. The `update_option()` is normally for data at the theme level.

Comment: oh man that is not good. can you do a var_dump($_POST) in the beginning of your options_init function

Comment: Orlando, your a genius! it works! Perfect. please can you do me a big favour I am learning PHP so not fully understood exactly what passing the variable here is doing? update_option('brand_color', $brand);

Comment: Sure so update_option() creates a record in the wp_options database, you a creating a record with the key brand_color and the value of whatever is in brand. Here is a layout of the wordpress tables. https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/25/WP4.4.2-ERD.png After you create that record you can access it with get_option(). When you want to set an option for Wordpress or a theme its good to use update_option() if its going to be like a per user option or per post than user update_user_meta or update_post_meta

Comment: Thats brilliant, thank you so much for taking the time to assist, I truly appreciate it!